# Infinitisemal generator of a semigroup with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators, parabolic-pde

When we talk about evolution equation the first idea who comes to the mind is the semigroups theory, this theory deals with the Cuachy problems of the form $$\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = Au$$
where $A$ is an operator acts ob Banach spaces to another.
My question is  : is there any theory which deals with the evolution problems of the form $$\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial t}} = A(t)u$$
this time $A$ depends on $t$  ? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are known as nonautonomous problems, and have been studied extensively, including through the lens of semigroup theory. See for example Lunardi's book *Analytic Semigroups and Optimal Regularity in Parabolic Problems*, in particular chapter 6.

Answer (score 1):

The appendix in the book [*Evolution Equations in Thermoelasticity*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wHsqZeo5eF8C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false) is another source. This book presents a theory for nonhomogeneous linear equations having the form
$$U_t+A(t)U=F(t)$$
which enable us to treat nonlinear evolution equations via fixed-point method.

For example, the nonlinear equation
$$u_{tt}-[a(u_{x})]_x=0$$
can be written as
$$u_{tt}-a'(u_{x})u_{xx}=0.\tag{$1$}$$

Setting a "nice" function $\tilde{u}$, we obtain (from the theory in the said book) existence of solution for the linear equation
$$u_{tt}-a'(\tilde{u}_{x})u_{xx}=0\tag{2}.$$

In this case, the nonautonomous operator is
$$A(t)=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 &-I\\ -a'(\tilde{u}_x(t))\partial_{xx}&0\end{matrix}\right).$$

From the Banach fixed-point theorem applied to the map
$$\tilde{u}\mapsto\text{solution of }(2)$$
we obtain existence of local solution for $(1)$.

(Of course, to apply the method we need some regularity conditions on the nonlinearity $a$ as well as on the initial data.)